# Determining area of graph based on unknown boundaries bounded by special trigonometry graphs

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, area

Interesting question for all to solve that i chanced upon luckily.

let the area bounded by two graphs below from $m \pi $ to $(n-1) \pi $  be A, where $m$ and $n$ are integers. Express $n-m$ in terms of A. $$y = 2cos(x)$$ $$y= sin(2x) $$

Comment: "Interesting question for all to solve that i chanced upon luckily." Your happiness faced to this issue is sympathetic, but recognize that it is rather artificial : explain for example why you are specialy interested by these bounds... Is there a connection with the intersection points of the curves ?

Comment: ah i have missed out an important condition that m and n are both integers. Sorry to those who have seen the question already!